# Rascal: parsing string with multiple "_"s

Tags: parsing, syntax-error, dsl, rascal

I try to parse a string containing multiple "_"s, but I get a CallFailed exception.

I have tried to create a small as possible example of the problem syntax.

```
layout Layout = WhitespaceAndComment* !>> [\ \t\n\r#];
lexical WhitespaceAndComment = [\ \t\n\r] | @category="Comment" "#" ![\n]* $;

syntax SourceList = sourceList: "$"? "{"? Id sourceFile "}"?;
lexical Id = ([a-zA-Z/.\-][a-zA-Z0-9_/.]* !>> [a-zA-Z0-9_/.]) \ Reserved;
keyword Reserved = 
"$" | "{" | "}" ;
```

I am unable to parse this small example.

```
rascal>try { parse(#SourceList, "test"); } catch CallFailed(m, e): println("<m> : <e>");
|prompt:///|(25,9,<1,25>,<1,34>) : [type(sort("SourceList"),(sort("SourceList"):choice(sort("SourceList"),{prod(label("sourceList",sort("SourceList")),[opt(lit("$")),layouts("$default$"),opt(lit("{")),layouts("$default$"),label("sourceFile",lex("Id")),layouts("$default$"),opt(lit("}"))],{})}),layouts("$default$"):choice(layouts("$default$"),{prod(layouts("$default$"),[],{})}),empty():choice(empty(),{prod(empty(),[],{})}),lex("Id"):choice(lex("Id"),{prod(lex("Id"),[conditional(seq([\char-class([range(45,47),range(65,90),range(97,122)]),conditional(\iter-star(\char-class([range(46,57),range(65,90),range(95,95),range(97,122)])),{\not-follow(\char-class([range(46,57),range(65,90),range(95,95),range(97,122)]))})]),{delete(keywords("Reserved"))})],{})}),keywords("Reserved"):choice(keywords("Reserved"),{prod(keywords("Reserved"),[lit("$")],{}),prod(keywords("Reserved"),[lit("}")],{}),prod(keywords("Reserved"),[lit("{")],{})}))),"${test}"]
ok
```

A changed sourcefile from "test" to "${test}" gives exactly the same output.

The complete syntax in which SourceList is embedded has many more rules. But then I get the following results.

```
set(${TARGET_NAME}_DEPS
    GenConfiguration_OBJ_TN_Common # accept
    ${COMMON_BB_PCMDEPS}  # reject
    COMMON_BB_PCMDEPS # accept
    COMMON_BB_PCM_DEPS # reject
)
```

for which I want to have a solution.

What is wrong with the minimal example? Why is test or ${test} not accepted?

BTW: I am using the latest unstable. Does it make sense to install and try the stable release?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your problem, but it seems to work here:

```
rascal>parse(#SourceList, "test")
SourceList: (SourceList) `test`
```

The unstable version is fine at the moment. In fact it's high time to release a stable version. So for now you're better off with the unstable version.

The `CallFailed` exception is confusing. It means that a function is called which can not be matched OR not be found. So maybe `parse` is not in scope by not importing `ParseTree`, or you have a different function called `parse` which does not have a `type[Tree]` and `str` as the expected parameters in scope. As long as the ParseTree module is imported, you're call to `parse` should be fine.

Please let me know if you have made progress. Perhaps a restart of Eclipse might clear up something as well.

Comment: Maybe @Matty has defined their own parse function, and forgot to import Parse tree?

Comment: The exception put me on the wrong track. I had indeed other overloaded parse methods active. After a restart and manual load of ParseTree it worked.

Comment: I also solved the original problem of the "_"s. By mistake I placed COMMON_BB_PCM_DEPS in the keywords set. After removing COMMON_BB_PCM_DEPS, it parses the instances.

Comment: Ok that's nice. We have to think hard how to report failing functions better. The static checker will certainly help with that if it's guaranteed no function will match at compile time, but the dynamic case requires certainly better explanation.  Thanks!